# Is a C# assembly file executable?

Tags: c#

Are assemblies basically executable files? Thanks. I'm writing more because I can't bypass quality standards and it needs more words in my current problem written in.

Comment: Have you tried Google this? Lucky shot from Google gave me an answer to your question in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not executable files. As it is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zst29sk2(v=vs.110).aspx):

> In general, a static assembly can consist of four elements:
>
> - The assembly manifest, which contains assembly metadata.
> - Type metadata.
> - Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) code that implements the types.
> - A set of resources.

Actually an assembly is loaded in the runtime environemt (CLR) and the MSIL code is compiled to native code on demand (this is called just in time compliation).